# How to delete all the lines after certain line in a file i python

Tags: python, file

Hi I have a number of files that I want to clean them from usefulness information by deleting all the contents that is after a certain line could you please tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work fine

```
import os 
for filename in os.listdir("path-to-your-directory")
  text=""
  with open(filename, "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
  with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write( text[ : text.find("text-that-you-are-looking-for") ] )
```